# First order PDEs (Cauchy Problem)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, intuition

Here is a theorem in my lecture notes:

> Let $S$ be a compatible $(d-1)$-dimensional $C^1$-hypersurface with $a, b \in C^1$ in a neighbourhood of $S$ and $g$ a $C^1$ function on $S$. For every $x_0 \in S$, there is a neighbourhood $\Omega$ of $x_0$ such that the Cauchy problem $$a(x, u) \cdot Du = b(x, u) \hspace{2mm}  \text{in}\hspace{2mm}  \Omega, \hspace{2mm} u = g \hspace{2mm} \text{on} \hspace{2mm} \Omega \cap S$$ has a unique solution $u \in C^1(\Omega)$
>
> [Note: we define $S$ to be compatible with the equation if $\nu(x) \cdot a(x, g(x)) \neq 0 \forall x \in S$]

So I'm first trying to understand the statement here because it's quite abstract (to me).

So I thought to try some PDEs out and see if they match the conditions in the statement, but I'm struggling to apply the statement's conditions in practice.

For example, suppose I have the PDE $$\partial_{x_1} u + 2\partial_{x_2}u = u, u(z, 0) = h(z)$$ for $h \in C^1$.

In this case, what would be my $S$? Is it compatible, I'm not sure how to 'verify' the compatibility condition in general?

Are there any examples where the statement fail and why? (Well I know there are, but I'm not too sure why they contradict the statement).

If someone could provide some examples of first order PDEs for which $S$ is **not** compatible, that would be very helpful I think.

Comment: Your $S$ is $x_2=0$ where the datum $g=h$ is given. Your normal vector $v$ is $(0,1)$ and $S$ is not characteristic since $a=(1,2)$ is not tangent to $S$ (not orthogonal to $v$). Your problem is thus well posed locally and has a solution unique in the neighborhood of any point in $S$.

Comment: Thank you, how about if my PDE is $\partial x_1 u + 3x_1^2 \partial x_2 u = 1, u(z, z^3) = 1$. This doesn't have a solution. What would be $S$? I'm thinking $x_2 = z^3$?

Comment: Yes, $S$ would be the cubic parabola $x_2=x_1^3$. The vector $a=(1,3x_1^2)$. The normal vector to $S$ is the gradient of $F(x_1,x_2)=x_2^2-x_1$, that is, $(-1,2x_2)$. The dot product is $=-1+6x_1^2x_2=-1+6x_1^5$ on your initial curve. Thus your curve is characteristic at just one point $x_1=1/\sqrt[5]{6}$. I do not see any reason why you might not have a solution unless you are in the neighborhood of the "bad" point $(1/\sqrt[5]{6},1/\sqrt[5]{6^3})$.